# Showing data in table row wise by using codeigniter php

Tags: php, sql, codeigniter

How can i show data in two row separately as shown in image [image]

I have tried this but i am not getting what i want. Also i don't want to use two loops separately.

```
<table class="tbl1">    
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <h1> date</h1> </td>
            <?php $i=1; foreach ($student as $value) { $i++;?>
            <td>
                <?php echo $value[ 'date']; ?>
                <?php } ?>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <h1>Status</h1> </td>
            <?php $i=1; foreach ($student as $value) { $i++; ?>
            <td>
                <?php echo $value[ 'status']; ?>
            </td>
            <?php } ?>    
        </tr>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Please post your controller code here.

Answer (score 0):

Do a single loop and in that loop include 2 `<tr>`s for date and status.

```
<table class="tbl1">
    <tbody>
    <?php foreach ($student as $value) { ?> 
    <tr>
        <td><h1> date</h1> </td>
        <td><?php echo $value['date']; ?>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><h1>Status</h1></td>
        <td><?php echo $value['status']; ?></td>
    </tr>
    <?php } ?>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Also i don't see the purpose of using `$i` here and what about the rest of the column in front of date and status.

Or if you want only 2 rows and display all data column wise then you could do it like

```
<?php
$dateHTML = '';
$statusHTML = '';
foreach ($student as $value) {
    $dateHTML .= '<td>'.$value['date'].'</td>';
    $statusHTML .= '<td>'.$value['status'].'</td>';
}
?>
<table class="tbl1">
    <tbody>
    <tr>
        <td><h1> date</h1> </td>
        <?php echo $dateHTML;?>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><h1>Status</h1></td>
        <?php echo $statusHTML;?>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: butt i have to break the line and show data in next row after every 3 records printing

Comment: @Usamaali you should update your question with complete details you want to achieve

Comment: bro i want after printing 3 records in first row my line will break and show data in next row(2nd Row). i cant post right i have to wait 90 mints

Comment: @Usamaali i really can't help you without viewing the expected output ? i am unsure you want to break the data but you are showing it column wise